# How to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for console application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services, aspnetcore-environment

I have the following simple console application that contains a hosted service:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // db context
                services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

                // hosted services
                services.AddHostedService<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService>();
                services.AddScoped<ProcessManuallySendings>();

                // services
                services.AddHttpClient<ISendPushService, SendPushService>(x
                    =>
                {
                    x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(65);
                });
            })
            .Build())
        {
            // Start the host
            await host.StartAsync();

            // Wait for the host to shutdown
            await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

It works with my database and it means that it requires connection string. I have three `appsettings.json` files:

[image]

On the development server I will use `Development` environment, on the production - `Production`. On my local machine I'm going to use `Local`. It's simple. 
I'm going to get it with the help of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` (OS environment variable).

I use Linux and in my shell (zsh) config file I have:

[image]

When I type in my terminal `$ echo $ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` I have `Local`.
But when I start my console application

```
$ dotnet run // in the project folder
```

It's trying to start with `Production` environment. 
See debug output:

[image]

So how to set environment? Why Os variable doesn't work?

Comment: What version of .net core are you using?

Comment: @Shoejep I'm using the last 3.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-configuration) for .Net Core 3.0 onwards, the host configuration is provided from environment variables prefixed with DOTNET_  (for example, DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT).

If that doesn't work, you could also try setting the environment variable in the launchSettings.json like this on your profile.

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT" : "Development"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

With .NET Core 3, the generic host [uses the `DOTNET_` prefix](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/5fe6ff74c3f95683d21e33cd6bf98e8e1477d6ed/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Host.cs#L63), not the old `ASPNETCORE_` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

When setting environment variables in rider for a console application in dotnet core 3.1, neither ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT nor DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT worked regardless of whether they were set in the Run/Debug Configuration or LaunchSettings.

In my situation, I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions and wanted hostEnvironment to be resolved correctly to **Development**.

```
if (hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new EfCommandInterceptor());
}
```

To get this working, I had to create an environment variable called **ENVIRONMENT** with the appropriate value.

```
ENVIRONMENT=Development
```